# Google Docs Ctrl + Shift + L not working

Tags: google-docs, keyboard-shortcuts

So <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> does nothing in Google Docs, where <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> work. I tried this on the same google doc but on my Chromebook, and it works. My laptop is Windows 10, so I figured something must have the shortcut of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> on my laptop which overrides the google doc, except nothing happens. Is there any way to solve that?

Comment: did you try to disable all extensions?

Comment: @user0 how do I do that?

Comment: either try incognito mode or paste this in the address bar `chrome://extensions/` and toggle off all extensions

Comment: @user0 just tried incognito. Same problem.

Answer (score 3):

*I had this problem recently and found this question so I will add an answer for others.*

I turned out to be a Chrome extension that was overriding the Google Docs hotkey.

I went to [chrome://extensions/shortcuts](http://chrome://extensions/shortcuts) and looked for an entry with `Ctrl + Shift + L` and reassigned it to another key. You could also, of course, delete the entry if you do not use the hotkey.